# Retrieving a specific value from "df -h" using shell

Tags: shell

When I use df -h, I get the following output:

> Filesystem            Size  Used Avail
>   Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
>                          59G  2.2G   54G   4% /
>
> /dev/sda1             122M   38M   78M
>   33% /boot
>
> tmpfs                 1.1G     0  1.1G
>   0% /dev/shm
>
> 10.10.0.105:/somepath
>
> ```
>                    11T  8.4T  2.1T  81% /storage4
> ```
>
> 10.11.0.101:/somepath
>
> ```
>                    15T  8.9T  5.9T  61% /storage1
> ```
>
> /dev/mapper/patha    5.0T  255G  4.8T
>   5% /storage5_vol0
>
> /dev/mapper/pathb    5.0T  195G  4.9T
>   4% /storage5_vol1
>
> /dev/mapper/pathc    5.0T  608G  4.5T
>   12% /storage5_vol2

I want to write a script that gets the value of ***Avail*** column on a specific storage.

I used to use

> df -k /storage_name | tail -1 | awk
>   '{print $3}'

But the ***FileSystem*** column can have a value or not .. which would change the variable of my script from $3 to $4.

How can I get the ***Avail*** on a single command line even if there are no values on the previous columns?

Comment: +1 interesting question. In case you do not get any answers here you might be interested in the separate [unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com). Simply flag for a mod to migrate this question

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/247670/retrieving-a-specific-value-from-df-h-using-shell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply turn on POSIX compatible output (-P) to df:

```
$ df -Pk /dev/sda1 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'
```

That ensures that the format of each line is the same (no line feed after long device names).

Comment: Thx. That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Use -P option to df, to make sure output is normalized, and not splitted to many lines.

And, anyway - you can also always use $(NF-2) to print available column.

Comment: Thx. That's exactly what I needed.
I chose Matt Jenkins answer just because he did it first.

Answer (score 0):

Work off the NF variable (number of fields). Something like :

df -k /storage_name|tail -1 |awk 'NF == 6 {print $3};NF == 5 {print $4}'

Comment: Instead he can just { print $( NF-2 ) }

Comment: It works for the situation I have right now. But not for a generic one, where could be no values on more than one column.

Answer (score 0):

```
df -k /dev | tail -1 | sed s/"^[^0-9]*"// | awk '{print $3}'
```

Adding the sed will remove all non-digit characters from the beginning of the line. You may need to modify it a bit if you have digits in your filesystem name